# Sorting my Favourites Q&A in directories/tags

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Hi

I have become really used to stackoverflow, and really appreciate it.
So much that now I have a 15 pages full of my favourites question/answers.

Some are really important, some only currently important, some for much more time. Not all are of primary importance. Some should be re-read often. Some shouldn't. Some are about C++. Others about Haskell. Some abouts books. Some about multi processing techniques....
Some about this... Some about that... Some about...

It would be a dream come true if I could:

1. Create my proper directories so as to
   organize my FAVs to read them again.
2. Sort my favourite Q&A by tags.

Do you think its a good idea, maybe already discussed ? 
can be added to a SO wishlist somewhere ?
(Is it the good place to ask for this ?)

Comment: Your option for tags is already possible. The Ninja Search Operator `infavorites:mine` lets you search through your favorites, so combine it with a tag search to effectively group by tag. For example, `infavorites:mine [c++]`.

Comment: how to learn about the possible Ninja Search Operators. Where is the reference to all of them ?

Comment: @GraceNote - does that still work?

Comment: @yhw42 This was removed several months ago, alas.

Comment: @GraceNote Seems it came back again. I have tested it right now and it's ok, it works just fine.