# How can I sort or filter my Stack Overflow favorite questions by tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting my Favourites Q&A in directories/tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76361/sorting-my-favourites-qa-in-directories-tags)

Whenever I like a question or think that a question might be useful for me for future reference I mark it as favorite. Now I have lot of questions as favorites. How do I filter them (my own favorites) based on the tags?

Like if I am implementing something with a technology, say C++ or [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework), and I know that I have some questions in the favorite list for these specific technology and I want to view them filtered as a reference any time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want separate lists per tag, just click on the tag and you'll get it, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++)

For your network-wide favorite tags all in one list, use the favorite tags filter. Go to [the filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/), and select "favorite tags" on the sidebar.

You can also create a custom filter, by clicking "new filter".

[image]

For example, I created the  [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) filter for you: https://stackexchange.com/filters/46869/c-and-entityframework

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I appreciate. Actually I mean favorite marked question not favorite tag. In this filter I cannot filter by whether the question is marked favorite by the user which is me. That is what I want. Filter based on the tags + question should be marked favorite for user.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: Oh, I doubt that that's possible. You can only see your favorites [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1063250/abhijit-kadam?tab=favorites), but you have a lot so I can see that you'd like to filter.

Comment: Ya, there are lot many and many more will be added. I want to sort them by tags. Any custom query I can write?

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: Not that I know of... :\