# How can I filter my Favorite questions based on a tag or set of tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, bookmarks

This question has been asked twice already, once [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134537/how-can-i-sort-or-filter-my-stack-overflow-favorite-questions-by-tags) and once [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76361/sorting-my-favourites-qa-in-directories-tags). However, the solution presented in the first question seems to no longer work, and the comments on the answer to the second question implies that it was not possible a year ago.

I wonder, is it possible today to list favorite **questions** by tag?

Note that this question has nothing to do with "favorite tags".

For example, I want to look at all my favorite questions, which are tagged with `vim`.

Is this possible either directly on the site or through the StackExchange API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It is possible:

```
infavorites:mine [vim]
```

Check out Advanced Search Tips in [Search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=).